# How to paginate entries united from two paginated sources

Tags: api, flickr

Currently, I have two functions, each of which fetches paginated entries from its own 3-d party RESTful API endpoint. Some received items can be repeated from these two endpoints. How to make my own function, that paginates the union of results returned from these functions without repeated entries? There is no way to do this in one API query, there is no such filter exposed.

In my case, I want to fetch photos from *Flickr* both by tag, either from specific photo set. So I have two functions (TypeScript):

```
interface PaginationParams {
    page:     number;    // better be offset, but FlickrAPI is page-based
    per_page: number;
}
interface RetVal {
    total:  number;
    photos: FlickrPhoto[];
}
interface FlickrPhoto { /* ... */ }
function fetchPhotosFromPhotoset(params: PaginationParams): Promise<Retval>;
function fetchPhotosByTag(params: PaginationParams): Promise<Retval>;

function fetchPhotosFromPhotosetAndByTag(params: PaginationParams): Promise<Retval> {
    // this function has to paginate results from fetchPhotosFromPhotoset() and
    // from fetchPhotosByTage() united without repeated entries
    // ??? 
}
```

By union, I imply OR operator.

**For now I see such solution**: fetch all items from first and second endpoint each time, delete repeated entries and then paginate result. But it's time- and memory- consuming.